# how to upload images to ftp server using spring MultipartFile without storing images in local disk

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Can anyone help me how to upload images to ftp server with out storing to local disk in spring, i tried it is uploading but it is storing images in same project work space and also in ftp server.

Below code which i tried?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/updateprofile1", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {


    FTPSClient con = getFTPConnection();

    try {

        con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    //  createDirectory(con, "test");
        showServerReply(con);
        System.out.println("Target directory: %s" + con.printWorkingDirectory());
        con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        con.enterLocalPassiveMode();


            con.changeWorkingDirectory("user/user_profile");
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String fileName = currrentTime.getTimeInMillis() + "_" + file.getName()+".jpg";
            boolean result = con.storeFile(fileName, file.getInputStream());
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Could not upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
    }

    return "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
}
public static FTPSClient getFTPConnection() {
    FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient();
    int reply;
    try {
        ftp.connect("1***4");
        ftp.login("****", "****);
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ftp.listDirectories().length; i++) {
                System.out.println(ftp.listDirectories());
            }
            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("user");
            showServerReply(ftp);
        //  LOGGER.info("-------->>> %s", ftp.printWorkingDirectory());
            showServerReply(ftp);
            //LOGGER.info("Connected Success");
        } else {
            //LOGGER.error("Connection Failed");
            ftp.disconnect();
            ftp = null;
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        //LOGGER.error("Error while trying to connect to the ImageBak Repository");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        ftp = null;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //LOGGER.error("Error while trying to connect to the ImageBak Repository");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        ftp = null;
    }

    return ftp;

}
private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
    String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
    if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
        for (String aReply : replies) {
            System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show us your code.

Comment: below code which i tried?

Comment: Please edit **the question** to add code instead of adding it as answers to this questions. It will be much easier to read. There are share/[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45077931/edit)/flag links just below question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) example, add Apache Commons Net to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

and then update `FileUploadController#handleFileUpload` something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    String FTP_ADDRESS = "your_address";
    String LOGIN = "you_login";
    String PSW = "you_password";

    FTPClient con = null;

    try {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect(FTP_ADDRESS);

        if (con.login(LOGIN, PSW)) {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            boolean result = con.storeFile(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream());
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "Could not upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: its working but ,i uploaded image but storing in file format

Comment: see the above code which i tried but it is storing in file format

Comment: I've edit my answer - changed `file.getName()` to `file.getOriginalFilename()` in `con.storeFile`. And don't forget to accepr/upvote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: thanks but i changed file.getName to multipartFile.getName()+".jpg"; its working